# ondraw view and xml in android

Tags: android

How can I draw an dynamic view on top of mainscreen in android.

For example I display the main screen using  setContentView(R.layout.main);
This draws many widgets and includes an image defined in main.xml this way :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/myImageView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/sinewave"/>
```

Now if I would like to draw rectangle on this image, how can I do it?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you read through the android docs?  Specifically, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

To draw something on screen instead of using a pre-defined Widget:

*You create a custom view class.*

> ```
> public class yourCustomView extends View {
> }
> ```

*You add that custom view to your xml layout.*

> ```
> <view class="your.package.path.yourCustomView"
>     android:id="@+id/myView"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="50dip"
>     /**you can add other xml attributes that are defined for View**/
> />
> ```

*You override the onDraw() method to make it draw stuff you want on its canvas.*

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
>     /**draw stuff here**/
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use this constructor if using the XML layout:

```
public yourCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
    super(context, attrs); 
}
```